# How to prevent before call same function on the object in the row?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to create a simple builder where I can pass a function and get a result, but I want to have a restrictions. For example I created:

```
class Compute {
    public Compute count(Function func){ ... }
    public Compute result() {...}
}
```

And now I can call it like that: `compute.count(function).result()`, but I cannot find out how to prevent before doing this `compute.count(function).count(function)` after `count` I could only call `result()` and could not call `count`. Also I want to call it in this style: `compute.count(function).result().count(function).result()`, but do not want to call same methods in a row. How to solve this problem?

Comment: probably nested static class for `result()` ?

Comment: I believe you should rethink why you designed both those APIs to return `Compute` and then deciding when to break the chain. Why not let them return different types?

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to create some boiler-plate code, here is a type safe way to achieve what you want (this is just an example, you can adjust it how you want):

```
static class User {

    static WithName builder() {
        return name -> age -> new User(name, age);
    }

    private User(String name, int age) {
        // whatever you want here
    }
}

interface WithName {

    WithAge withName(String name);
}

interface WithAge {

    User withAge(int age);
}
```

And a caller that looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User u = User.builder()
                 .withName("Bob")
                 .withAge(18);
}
```

Once you test this, you will see that methods can be called only in a particular order.

Comment: I am not sure if I could call now `withName` after `withAge`?

Comment: @allocer you can't. that is the entire point. you restrict users to build `User` only in a particular way, it's not very different than what you want.

Comment: I understand, but as I said I do not want only to call same methods in a row, so after `withAge` I could call `withName`, but after `withName` or `withAge` I cannot call same methods.

Comment: @allocer have you tried what I wrote? you seem to confuse yourself and me here

Comment: Your example is a good application of the builder pattern, but apparently, the OP can’t adapt it to the actual problem of the question, which has no terminal operation, but rather is supposed to allow alternating invocations. So you need something like `interface A { B foo(); } interface B { A bar(); }`, to allow `foo().bar().foo().bar()`, but neither `foo().foo()` nor `bar().bar()`.